# What is the parameter to set a tool tip in Windows .NET MAUI?

Tags: c#, maui

The default tooltip parameter is not available in .NET MAUI, and I'm unable to find anything in the docs.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, support for features that only make sense on platforms with a mouse, has not yet been added to Maui. (Tooltip requires Hover, which does not generally exist on a mobile platform.)

I personally don't expect to see this in first Maui release.

Add your interest as an upvote or a comment on [github maui issue - feature request - tooltip](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/1889).

Check there in a few months to see if there is any mention of adding it to [roadmap](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Roadmap), or to planned features.

Also pay attention to [maui - proposal - mouse moving over control](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3669). That is the more general category. Unfortunately, there are no comments by devs on that - maybe search to see if there is any similar proposal.

Comment: <ignorable>MacOS has a mouse, Windows has a mouse, so 50% of the main supported operating systems have a mouse ;-) Not having a tooltip limits a useful application to mobile devices.  Might as well have stuck with Xamarin for Android and WPF for Windows. ;-) </ignorable>

Comment: It is surprising that it isn't on the roadmap yet; it clearly needs to be added at some point. Shouldn't be too hard to do an unofficial solution, then get it vetted and incorporated. I would do that myself later this year, except that I'm currently working for an app client who doesn't need a Windows version. I expect someone to do this, sometime this year.

Comment: If developing primarily for desktop, one option is to develop for WinUI 3 (Windows App SDK) today. Keep an eye on Maui's progress; consider it in six months to a year.

Comment: That can't be entirely truie - FlyoutItems DO highlight when the mouse cursor is hovering over them.

Comment: @user2727133: Maui maps its controls into native controls of the platform it is running on. Whatever behavior that platform (here, Windows) has for its controls, such as highlighting in response to mouse hover, does function. Likewise, there may be functionality that Maui devs have made use of. Unfortunately, that doesn't imply the Maui app programmer has access to such functionality. I mean, not "built-in": you can write a custom handler for the type of control, to gain access to platform-specific functionality.

Comment: It's incredulous that one of THE most beneficial features of a mobile application i.e. the ability to know what a button does via a tooltip - is not available! Have the MAUI developers *ever* written anything for commercial users?? Even Xamarin - which has more holes in it than a swiss cheese - provided for tooltips ... My flabber is well and truly gasted.

Comment: @RichardHammond I've never seen a **mobile** app where a button has a tooltip - tooltip display requires a **mouse**. **Mobile device OSes do not include tooltips.** Perhaps we have some **terminology** confusion here? Regardless, StackOverflow isn't the place for rants about technology, no matter how well deserved!

Comment: Bottom line: Because Maui is based on Xamarin Forms, which started with **mobile** devices, the first phase of Maui has been about correcting deficiencies in implementation, of features that work on all platforms. Features that are specific to **desktop** platforms, and currently missing, should be added as issues at maui github. (Mouse+keyboard support already listed.) Until Maui has desktop-specific features, consider using **WinUI 3** (Windows Desktop App) instead.

Comment: I understood MAUI to be the successor to Xamarin so ... imho ... it should include ALL that Xamarin could (or should have done given it's Swiss cheese implementation) and that would include tooltips.  However, I don't care because I've dumped them both as being useless and now use Android Studio. So there!

Comment: Xamarin,Forms includes Tooltips? I’ve programmed in XF since the beginning, and that is news to me. Perhaps you mean that third-parties have implemented libraries that support tooltips? Right; a downside of Maui not being 100% backward-compatible with XF (a decision which was necessary, or we would have been forever limited by XF issues with performance and platform compatibility), is that it will take time for the ecosystem to mature. Re Android Studio: Huh? That is a non sequitur. But this isn’t the place to discuss cross-platform c# .Net 8 vs Kotlin.

Comment: I realize just now that we have a difference in terminology. Historically, a tooltip appeared on a mouse + GUI (desktop) platform, when mouse hovers over a control. When I said “mobile lacks tooltip”, that is what I was referring to. Literally impossible on a touch system. Searching now, I see that on mobile, “tooltip” now refers to touching a control, and having an info box appear. This can be coded in Maui, but its not as convenient as it could be. Is that what you were referring to?